# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined at app.js:22,this is the error i am getting.in browser,please resolve it

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to implement Firebase Phone Number Authentication as described 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RecaptchaVerifier' of undefined     at app.js:22
please go through the code ,i am not able to figure out.and reply has soon as possible.

app.js

```
// window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
//   'size': 'invisible',
//   'callback': function(response) {
//     // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
//     onSignInSubmit();
//   }
// });
//firebase.auth().languageCode = 'it';

// var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse(window.recaptchaWidgetId);
$('#verify_otp_model').hide()
$('#errorbox').hide()

// phone auth
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('getotp', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': function(response) {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      //onSignInSubmit();

    }
  });
  // [END appVerifier]

recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
    window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
  //  updateSignInButtonUI();
  });

 );
```

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDLFhLuJ_SOJDqLcJOi2-7tUhLrJ8wstZU",
    authDomain: "voting-6d410.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://voting-6d410.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "voting-6d410",
    storageBucket: "voting-6d410.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "769418906177",
    appId: "1:769418906177:web:852a15ba5e50033fd514c0",
    measurementId: "G-37YQP4X9WG"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
    </head>
    <body class="gray-bg">
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises due to the Firebase JS SDK version. I solved by changing to this version -

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the new version, change your script with

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
```